# Angular directive for not allowing only spaces or tabs to be pasted?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, formgroups

Oddball edge case here, I am trying to find a way to prevent the pasting of only spaces or tabs in a fairly lengthy form in the required textareas (to shortcut through the form is their concern), and I guess, if there's a tab or space in front of actual text, then trim it so it's not visible?

I'm working on something along the lines of (within an onPaste(event) in my directive):

```
const cleanedString = pastedText.replace('/\t/','');
```

and seeing if it leads with a tab or space, then trim that:

```
pastedText.charCodeAt(0) === 9/32, etc..
```

Any ideas? Thank you, this one has been tricky without throwing a $event.preventDefault(); for a valid paste.

Thank you very much for looking!

Comment: Can you use a regex to see if there are only spaces or tabs? But even then what's to stop the user mashing the keyboard for each field? Probably quicker than all spaces or tabs (how would adding tabs to a form even be possible? Copy/paste?

Comment: Hi, I should have noted more clearly, I have the onKey input handled, it's the pasting portion that has me stumped.

Comment: No, I should have read the question properly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out event.preventDefault(); was my friend. I skipped the regex and just used trim();

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
onPaste(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
    let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
    let trimmedText = pastedText.trim();
    if (trimmedText.length > 0) {
        this.formControl.control.setValue(trimmedText);
        this.formControl.control.setValidators(this.validators);
        this.formControl.control.updateValueAndValidity();
    } else {
        this.formControl.control.markAsTouched();
    }
}
```